# How to extract values of particular instance variable from Map using Java Stream API?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a HashMap, for each key the value is a User Defined Object. This user defined object has variable of type ArrayList. How can I extract this ArrayList into one List using Java stream API. So, the size of my HashMap is 3. Size of the array list inside each user defined object is   1. Final out should be an arraylist of size 3

My object is

```
class XYZ{
    List<ABC> list;
}
```

My map has values `{"1", XYZ_1},{"2",XYZ_2},{"3",XYZ_3}.` I want to extract list from each object `XYZ_1, XYZ_2,XYZ_3`

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: class XYZ{ List<ABC> list;} My map has values {"1", XYZ_1}{"2",XYZ_2},{"3",XYZ_3}. I want to extract list from each object XYZ_1, XYZ_2,XYZ_3

Comment: Update your question with this information rather than posting on the comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `Stream::flatMap`

```
Map<Key, List<CustomClass>> map = new HashMap<>();

List<CustomClass> data = map.values().stream()
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**EDIT**

Since you have a class with a list inside, you can change your code to look like this

```
Map<KeyClass, CustomClass> map = new HashMap<>();

List<?> data = map.values().stream()
                    .map(CustomClass::getList)
                    .flatMap(List::stream)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```